# JavasScript event handling best practice?

Tags: javascript, dom-events

When defining a JavaScript call, like so:

```
<input type="button" onclick="someJavaScriptFunction" />
```

What is the best way to write the actual call? I've seen numerous method:

```
javascript:someJavascriptFunction();
```

or

```
justSomeJavaScriptFunction();
```

or

```
withoutTheSemicolon()
```

Are there any benefits or caveats to any of the methods? I realize that using `addEventListener` is more flexible in certain cases.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want *best* practice, separate markup from script content.  Assign your event handlers in `script` elements. As you say, using `addEventListener` is one way of doing this, although you have to use `attachEvent` as well if you want to support versions of Internet Explorer before version 9.

It's perfectly valid, however, to assign `onevent` properties.  For instance:

```
<script>
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('yourID').onclick = function() {
           alert('element clicked');
        };
    };
</script>
```

This may well suit your purpose adequately, if you only have a few items.

Answer (score 5):

The best practice itself is to use JavaScript itself to attach the events:

Firefox, Chrome, Safari, Opera...

```
document.getElementById('someID').addEventListener('click', function() {
    function1();
    function2();
    function3();
});
```

IE:

```
document.getElementByID('someID').attachEvent('onclick', function() {
    function1();
    function2();
    function3();
});
```

Combine the two to get it to work.

Also, use premade frameworks like MooTools or JQuery to make this even easier.

Answer (score 2):

```
javascript:someJavascriptFunction();
```

We use `javascript:` as URL in `href` attribute or in bookmark address filed (bookmarklets). 
For example:

```
<a href="javascript:myFunction()">click me</a>
```

We use semicolon to attach more than one JavaScript instruction:

```
<span onclick="alert('first');alert('second')">click me</span>
```

`addEventListener` allows to attach many functions to same event:

```
element.addEventListener ('click', firstFunction);
element.addEventListener ('click', secondFunction);
```

Answer (score 1):

With or without the semicolon makes no difference, however the event is actually a line of javascript not just a function name so you could use the semicolon to add multiple functions like so:

```
<input type="button" onclick="function1();function2();function3();" />
```

I'm not sure javascript: will work at all, that is just if you attach a function as an href on a link, not as an event handler like below:

```
<a href="javascript:function1();function2();function3();" >A link</a>
```

Comment: @Colin: It will, but only coincidence. See my comment on your answer.

Answer (score 1):

`javascript:someJavascriptFunction();` Explicitly state to use javascript, in the case that you may have multiple/different scripts types such as ECMA Script.

`someJavascriptFunction()` is fine if you only have Javascript(s) on your page (rather than having multiple script types.

`someJavascriptFunction();doSomethingElse();return false;` Semi-colon used to chain/have multiple statements.

So there is no 'best' way, just what makes most sense, and is your preferred convention (in most cases).

Comment: No. `javascript:` in an event handler attribute specifies nothing about the language being used, and it's only the fact that it is coincidentally valid JavaScript syntax (it creates a label, in case you're interested) that prevents it throwing an error.

Answer (score 0):

addEventListener is the best way

Comment: IE8 is IE, IE is a program to download <some normal browser>