# How to call some JavaScript from an HTML Buttons

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I'm new to JavaScript. I have an HTML file with a button, I would need to call the following JS when a button is clicked. Any idea how to do it `<input type="submit" value="Get Push Token" />`?

Please provide me a sample of code.

```
PushToken.getToken(     
                     ["getToken"] ,           
                     function(token) {
                              global.token = token; 
                     },
                     function(error) {
                              console.log("Error : \r\n"+error);      
                     }
          );
```

---

```
 <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
        <meta name = "format-detection" content = "telephone=no"/>
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width;" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>Hello Cordova</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>Apache Cordova™</h1>
            <div id="deviceready">
                <p class="status pending blink">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="status complete blink hide">Device is Ready</p>
                <p>Click here to get the Token<input type="submit" value="Get Push Token" />
            </div>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova-2.0.0.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/PushToken.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think this question is too easy to be part of separate answer. this button is not a normal button, so I would recommend with submit write something like 

`<input type = "butoon" onsubmit=x();/>`
In your js

`function x() {

}`

Comment: please write a comment if you down-vote, so I can improve the question.. may thanks

Comment: first of all use input type button.

Comment: Thanks  Dhruvenkumar Shah for your comment, unfortunately I'm not able to solve it I'm a really beginner. if you are able to reply to me I would really appreciate that. Thanks for commenting

Comment: not to be mean here or anything, but any simple google would have given you the answer

Comment: upvotingg because  I think stackoverflow is good for learning, even for beginner, I am here to help

Comment: @DhruvenkumarShah, I agree, just to clarify, dont read w3schools, EVER. just prefix your searches with `mdn`, mozilla developer network

Comment: Don't use w3schools, their docs are not easy to read, promote good js documentation and use [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Without Using jQuery

In a simple component or application, you wouldn't want to require the entire jQuery library, so the simplest way to do it would be like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="Get Push Token" id="getPushToken" />
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('getPushToken').onclick=function(){
      PushToken.getToken(     
                 ["getToken"] ,           
                 function(token) {
                          global.token = token; 
                 },
                 function(error) {
                          console.log("Error : \r\n"+error);      
                 }
      );
}
```

## Using jQuery

If you're building a complex application, there's a good chance you'll be wanting jQuery for something else, in which case you may as well do it like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="Get Push Token" id="getPushToken" />
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#getPushToken').click(function(){
      PushToken.getToken(     
                 ["getToken"] ,           
                 function(token) {
                          global.token = token; 
                 },
                 function(error) {
                          console.log("Error : \r\n"+error);      
                 }
      );
});
```

## Understanding what's going on

In either case, the key point is that you wrap the code you want to execute in a function, and set it as the handler of the click event for that button.  The button will then cause the function to be called.

## Using the correct HTML

If the button is not within a form, you should probably use:

```
<button id="getPushToken">Get Push Token</button>
```

for the html instead, the JavaScript would be exactly the same.

Answer (score 1):

HTML:

```
<input type="submit" value="Get Push Token" id="getPushToken" />
```

JavaScript:

```
document.getElementById('getPushToken').onclick=function(){
      PushToken.getToken(     
                 ["getToken"] ,           
                 function(token) {
                          global.token = token; 
                 },
                 function(error) {
                          console.log("Error : \r\n"+error);      
                 }
      );
}
```

Anyway you have an input with `type="submit"`, but you haven't any form, that's a bit nonsense.

If you just want a button, use `type="button"`. If you want to submit a form, create a form which contains that input and whose `id` is, for example, `myform`. Then,

```
document.getElementById('myform').onsubmit=function(){
      PushToken.getToken(     
                 ["getToken"] ,           
                 function(token) {
                          global.token = token; 
                 },
                 function(error) {
                          console.log("Error : \r\n"+error);      
                 }
      );
}
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Put the code inside an event handling function, and then call that function in the `onclick` of the button.

HTML:

```
/* you probably want button, not submit, and it should have an ID */
<input type="button" id="someID" value="Get Push Token" />
```

JS:

```
document.getElementById('someID').onclick = function () {
    // whatever you want to do here
};
```

Note that there are other ways to bind event handlers, but this is considered the best practice (keep javascript and HTML separated)

Related question: [JavasScript event handling best practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6268946/javasscript-event-handling-best-practice)